# PHP uploading a file not working

Tags: php, file, upload

The code below is to upload files to a local folder. Once I select a file from the Dialog Box, it should display "OK" to confirm selection of file. But the code below is not working as required.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if(isset($name))
{
if(!empty($name))
        echo 'OK';
else
            echo 'Please chose a file';
}

?>

<form action="up.php" method="POST" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Is this even the same script?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

If you are not seeing anything in there on post, then you may need to set the following in your php.ini file:

```
file_uploads = On;
```

You may also need to change the allowed file sizes in the php.ini file if the file you are trying to upload is bigger than what is allowed:

```
post_max_size = 8M; make larger if needed
upload_max_filesize = 8M; make larger if needed*
```

After making these changes make sure to restart your webserver (apache/nginx.)

* *upload_max_filesize should never be bigger than post_max_size*

......